# ATA100 IDE HDD vs ATA100 IDE SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

**UPDATE:**

Bought a cheap 32GB SSD, and it's made a difference.  Most apps now take no more than 2 seconds to open, many seem to open within a second.  Apps like Google Chrome now take about 5 seconds to load instead of 20 seconds.

> **From the original question:**
>   The current read speed of the HDD is about 20MB/s, and it seems that a
>   cheap SSD ATA100 IDE drive is about 60MB/s.

Just tested this, my old HDD was giving me about 20MB/s, this new SSD is giving me about 70MB/s.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have an old laptop (CPU:P4, RAM:1GB) which has an ATA100 IDE HDD 20GB which is very slow.  I hear it seeking when I open applications and it takes about 20 seconds to load google chome.

My question is, if I buy a small (around 20GB) ATA100 IDE SSD, will that make things load faster?

My main use for the laptop is office productivity, loading applications, where I simply need it to boot faster and load office type apps and an internet browser quicker.

I do nothing on this laptop which is CPU or GPU intensive.

The current read speed of the HDD is about 20MB/s, and it seems that a cheap SSD ATA100 IDE drive is about 60MB/s.

Comment: I wouldn't waste money on it.

Comment: Very likely, yes. But, I agree with Tetsujin

Comment: You can get a faster used laptop for the price of a brand new SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. If it’s really a 20 GB HDD, it’s ancient. It’s a notebook HDD, too, making it even slower. Installing a SSD will be a tremendous improvement.

Currently, the Transcend Industrial series seems to relatively reasonably priced and available.

Answer (score 2):

Not much, because I think not only the hdd is the problem.

And the ATA/100 is slow... If you buy an SSD won't be (much) faster.

Also, that 1 GB RAM is not really good for using chrome because chrome eats RAM.

And yes, agree with comments.

Comment: Firefox doesn't slow down with 1 GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will.

But.

First, explore if you will not be better of buying mSATA ssd and an adapter SATA to IDE... You can then replace whole drive for less than old IDE connector ssd.

Second, make sure you use operating system that supports TRIM function. ANd that would be Windows 7 or newer. YOu can do without, but it's a pain and used ssd have already mileage, so it's always better to have than not.